# difference between int *a[3] and int (*a)[3]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to know what is a difference between :

```
int *a[3];
```

And

```
int (*a)[3];
```

Thanks a lot , good luck .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int *a[3]` => `a` is array of  `int *`

`(a+1)` will point to next integer by with the increment of integer size.

`int (*a)[3]` => a pointer to array of 3 integers

`(a+1)` will point to next array of 3 integers, with the increment of (3 * integer size)

to find details read more about pointer to arrays

Answer (score 3):

`int *a[3];` <- Array of 3 integer pointers

`int (*a)[3];` <- Pointer to Array of 3 integers